# Unit tests and setlocale()

Tags: php, internationalization, locale

I tried to write a UnitTest using PHPUnit which compares the `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` output. The problem is, when you have set different locale codes for different categories. You end up with a separated list of all categories with their corresponding locale.

But this list looks different on OSX and Linux.

**OSX**

```
en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

**Linux**

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
```

What's the best option to handle that in a PHPUnit test?

Comment: I test code which sets locale codes. And to compare the before and after I use a call to the `setlocale()` function.